# Find out when my asynchronous call is finished

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, alassetslibrary

I iterate through a list of photo albums on a iOS device. After having iterated through this group I want to simply print out the number of albums that were found.

What do I have to change in my code that the `NSLog` statement is only executed, when all the albums were loaded.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];      
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

void (^groupBlock)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
    if (group == nil){return;}
    [tempArray addObject:group];
 };

void (^failureBlock)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"A problem occured %@", [error description]);                                     
};  

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:groupBlock 
                     failureBlock:failureBlock];   

NSLog(@"%i albums were loaded", tempArray.count);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `groupBlock` will receive a group of `nil` when the enumeration is completed, so change:

```
if (group == nil){return;}
```

to

```
NSLog(@"%i albums were loaded", tempArray.count);
```

---

From the Class reference:

> When the enumeration is done, *enumerationBlock* is invoked with group set to `nil`.

[<sup>[source]</sup>](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)